# How can I select both hidden and visible td elements in a table row? (without using a special class attribute)

Tags: jquery, html

How can I select both hidden and visible td elements in a table row??

*(i.e., without using a special class attribute)*

The operation, below, only selects "visible" td's...

```
    jq('#page0grid tr td:not(:last-child').each(function () {
        console.log(jq(this).html());
    });
```

How could I modify this selector to retrieve ***both*** visible ***and*** hidden td values?

Comment: what do you mean, "hidden"? As in `display: none` in CSS? DOM doesn't care about that kind of thing. a DOM node exists, or it doesn't. Its visibility in the browser is irrelevant to that fact.

Comment: You are correct, Marc B.      I am working with "datatables.js" and had mistakenly assumed that columns marked ["visible": false] would simply be styled as "display:none" (or, the like) - but, would still be present.  This is NOT the case.   Hidden values are stored within the datatables object, only, apparently.   - Note:  I had ventured to withdraw/delete this question but, a stackoverflow "popup" warned against doing so.

Answer (score 0):

example for visible:

```
$( "div:visible" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).css( "background", "yellow" );
});
```

and invisible:

```
$('div').not(:visible);
```

So with your code:

```
$('#page0grid tr td:visible').each(function () {
        // for visible
});

$('#page0grid tr td').not(:visible).each(function () {
        // for invisible
});
```

Comment: Thank you Wahyu for reading my post.   Based on what I now realize - I certainly should NOT have posted this question.   Being in somewhat of a tight deadline, I acted hastily and regret doing so.  - My apologies.